# Manipulating image/gif files and their .bin or .dat representations, and then converting them back to image/gif representation

Tags: python, image, png, gif, bin

I'm trying to play around with Python and image/gif files and their .bin or .dat representations. For instance, I want to take a PNG file, convert it to its .bin or .dat file (its binary version), and then do something to manipulate the image, such as turning it from greyscale to black-and-white, or taking a black-and-white image and inverting all of the 0s and 1s so that the black parts become white and the white parts become black, and then convert it back into an actual image/gif. For instance, doing the black-to-white flipping for this PNG image:

[image]

This is kind of like a hands-on educational exercise to better understand the relation between images and binary.

I want to do this using the Python standard library functions, similar to what would be available in C. I don't want to use external libraries like numpy or opencv.

I can't seem to find any sources that explain this in a straight-forward way. How can I do this?

---

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import base64

with open("984269812_1.png", "rb") as f:
    png_encoded = base64.b64encode(f.read())

encoded_b2 = "".join([format(n, '08b') for n in png_encoded])

print(encoded_b2)

flippedBinary = ''.join('1' if x == '0' else '0' for x in encoded_b2)
print(flippedBinary)

# first split into 8-bit chunks
bit_strings = [flippedBinary[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(flippedBinary), 8)]

# then convert to integers
byte_list = [int(b, 2) for b in bit_strings]

with open('byte.dat', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytearray(byte_list))  # convert to bytearray before writing
```

This just inverts the bits for the previous image and produces a .dat file. I haven't been able to convert this back to a PNG image, and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: What is the issue? Read the binary into a bytes array, manipulate the data, and write is back to a binary file. Please post the C code that performs a simple manipulation as described - make a reproducible example with input and output (be specific to select Grayscale or RGB data or "indexed format"). Start a Python code that reads and writes binary file to and from a bytes array. Make clear that the conversion from/to PNG is allowed to use OpenCV.

Comment: @Rotem I'll post what I've tried so far.

Comment: You are not doing any favors, just follow the rules of [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There should be no base64 involved in this at all. Remember images (PNG/JPEG/GIF) have headers with metadata at the start and they are also compressed. It is not the case that the first byte of an image corresponds to the pixel at the top-left corner.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Would you please show me how to do this with just the Python standard library functions? Similar to how someone would do it using the standard C functions.

Comment: Not sure which aspect you want to do with standard library functions - it would take an experienced programmer weeks to read a JPEG/PNG from scratch which is why I suggested you use external tools to convert to a simple, uncompressed 1 byte/pixel format so you can concentrate on image processing rather than PNG/JPEG decoding/encoding.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hmm, interesting. The problem with ImageMagick is that it doesn't seem to be standard on operating systems.

Comment: **ImageMagick** is available for macOS, Linux and Windows. `ffmpeg` is an alternative tool to achieve the same thing. There's no mention of any specific OS, or compatibility in the question, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a colour or greyscale PNG/GIF/JPEG image, you can turn it into a greyscale 1 byte/pixel BIN file with **ImageMagick** in the Terminal like this:

```
magick IMAGE.JPG -colorspace gray -depth 8 GRAY:IMAGE.BIN
```

If your input image was 60x40, your BIN file will be 2,400 bytes or 1 byte/pixel. If your image was black, all bytes will be zero. If it was white, they'll all be 255.

---

Now do your Python thing, remembering to open with `"rb"` flags for binary reading of `"IMAGE.BIN"` and `"wb"` flags for binary writing of the processed data into `"PROCESSED.BIN"`

Off the top of my head, and untested, the Python to invert an image would look something like:

```
with open("IMAGE.BIN", "rb") as in, open("PROCESSED.BIN", "wb") as out:
    while True:
        # Read 1 pixel
        b = in.read(1)
        if b is null:
            break
        # Write inverted pixel
        out.write(255-b)
```

---

Convert the processed data back to a final PNG/GIF/JPEG result with:

```
magick -depth 8 -size 60x40 GRAY:PROCESSED.BIN result.png
```

Notice when converting from a raw, binary file (which unlike a PNG/JPEG doesn't have metadata at the start with image width and height), you need to tell **ImageMagick** the dimensions.

---

If you want to try decoding/encoding a proper image, with a header and metadata, I would suggest you try [PGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PGM_example) format first because it's easy. **Adobe Photoshop**, QuickLook/Preview, **GIMP**, `feh` and others can read and write them. So you would go from PNG/JPEG to PGM with:

```
magick IMAGE.PNG -colorspace gray -depth 8 IMAGE.PGM
```

Now do your Python processing, remembering to deal with the header, and then go back to PNG/JPEG with:

```
magick PROCESSED.PGM result.png
```

Note that you no longer need to tell **ImageMagick** the width and height because they are in the PGM header.

Once you have 8-bit PGM understood, you can move to 16-bit PGM. Then you can go to [PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#PPM_example) format to support colour.

---

Note that, if you have old, version 6 **ImageMagick** installed, you'll need to change from `magick` to `convert` throughout my answer - or, preferably upgrade to v7.

---

Note that all **ImageMagick** commands I have used in this answer can equally be expressed using `ffmpeg` if that is closer to your heart.

Going from PNG/JPEG to BIN, is along these lines:

```
ffmpeg -i IMAGE.JPG -pix_fmt gray -f rawvideo IMAGE.BIN
```

and the other direction (BIN/raw to PNG) like thus:

```
ffmpeg -video_size 60x40 -pix_fmt gray -f rawvideo -i PROCESSED.BIN result.png
```

Comment: `zsh: command not found: magick`

Comment: You would need to install **ImageMagick**. On macOS, that'd be via **homebrew** with `brew install imagemagick`. On Linux, `sudo apt install imagemagick` and change `magick` in my answer to `convert`.

Comment: He might already have Imagemagick 6. If so change magick to convert in each command.